# Angular - OAuth - loading twice or two redirects - How to stop reloading/refreshing

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using an Angular app with OAuth2  google authentication.

I have authGuard for certain endpoints, and it seems there is a flicker or double loading the same page. The console is also getting cleared(?) How can I identify the issue - any double reloading?

**Note**: I am not using angularx-social-login. Spring backend creates JWT Token

The class is

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService,
      @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document
    ) {
    }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      const isAuthenticated = !!this.tokenStorage.getUser();
      if(isAuthenticated) {        
        return true;
      }       
      const googleURL = AppConstants.GOOGLE_AUTH_URL;      
      window.location.href=googleURL;    
  }  
}
```

constants:

```
export class AppConstants {
  private static NG_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8081/";
   private static API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";
  
  private static OAUTH2_URL = AppConstants.API_BASE_URL + "oauth2/authorization/";
  
  private static REDIRECT_URL = "?redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(AppConstants.NG_BASE_URL+"#/home");

  public static API_URL = AppConstants.API_BASE_URL + "api/";
  public static AUTH_API = AppConstants.API_URL + "auth/";
  public static GOOGLE_AUTH_URL = AppConstants.OAUTH2_URL + "google" + AppConstants.REDIRECT_URL;

  public static SERVER="/server";  
}
```

app routing ...snippet

```
 {
    path: 'test/:id', 
    component: MyComponent, // child route component that the router renders
    data: { endpoint: 'test' },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canDeactivate: [MyRouteGuard]
  },
```

**EDIT**: Possible Problem - once the control comes back, OnInit calls the below, and does a "reload" - without this, the login button is not changing/toggling to signed In state (still shows SignIn, not Sign Out)

So how can I resolve this without reload?

```
  //used in init
  login(user): void {
    this.tokenStorage.saveUser(user);
    this.isLoginFailed = false;
    this.isLoggedIn = true;
    this.currentUser = this.tokenStorage.getUser();
      window.location.reload();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried fix using

1.

```
this.router.navigate([this.router.url])
```

2. 

onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' in app routing

> imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation:
> 'reload', relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy', useHash: true })],